# Why is PDO fetchAll() returning me same results twice?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm building a simple search engine in PHP with PDO. Everything works but fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) is returning me same results twice.

Here is my PHP code :
(Updated to display the **id** column...)

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$q = db()->prepare("SELECT id, title, description, type, mediaId FROM projects WHERE title LIKE ?");
$q->execute(array('%'.$search.'%'));
$d = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($d);
```

Here are the results I get from PDO

```
[
{
"id" : "1",
"title": "PhonArt",
"description": "Games",
"type": "",
"mediaId": "linkA"
},
{
"id" : "1",
"title": "PhonArt",
"description": "Games",
"type": "",
"mediaId": "linkA"
},
{
"id" : "2",
"title": "BioState",
"description": "Biology",
"type": "",
"mediaId": "linkB"
},
{
"id" : "3",
"title": "SnaPhones Inc.",
"description": "A social network",
"type": "",
"mediaId": "linkC"
},
{
"id" : "2",
"title": "BioState",
"description": "Biology",
"type": "",
"mediaId": "linkB"
},
{
"id" : "3",
"title": "SnaPhones Inc.",
"description": "A social network",
"type": "",
"mediaId": "linkC"
}
]
```

Comment: No, I checked, there isn't...

Comment: Code updated ! In fact, it's just a basic json_encode() to return JSON...

Comment: Is there a primary key in the table that can be included in the result, like a unique ID? I'm curious to see whether they are actually the same rows duplicated in the array.

Comment: Yes, Code updated !

Comment: Odd. [I can't reproduce the duplicates](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/019759/1).

Comment: Obviously, it's just impossible. You need to create an [isolated example](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mcve) to realize that your problem is elsewhere